# Creating new tags in a Select2 tag textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, tags, jquery-select2

I have an input (textarea) that has Select2's tags applied to it. So when a user types in the name of an item that exists in my data base, it shows a list of matching items and the user can select one and a tag is created.

Here is my code so far for basic tag functionality:

```
$('#usualSuppliers').select2({
        placeholder: "Usual suppliers...",
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        multiple: true,
        id: function(e) {
            return e.id + ":" + e.name;
        },
        ajax: {
            url: ROOT + 'Ajax',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: function(term, page) {

                return {
                    call: 'Record->supplierHelper',
                    q: term,
                    page_limit: 10
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page) {
                return {
                    results: data.suppliers
                };
            }
        },
        formatResult: formatResult,
        formatSelection: formatSelection,
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {
            var data = [];
            $(element.val().split(",")).each(function(i) {
                var item = this.split(':');
                data.push({
                    id: item[0],
                    title: item[1]
                });
            });
            //$(element).val('');
            callback(data);
        }
    });
```

Is there a way for a new tag to be created if the text typed does not exist? Initially I thought this could some how be done by delimiting with spaces, but some items (supplier names) will have spaces in them, so that won't work.

I think when no matches are found the user needs to somehow "create" the tag by pressing a button that could appear in the drop down box, but I have no idea how to do this.

How can I allow users to create new tags that may have spaces in them and still be able to carry on adding more tags, existing or otherwise?

Comment: Usage with `textarea` has since been deprecated, `<select` is the recommended method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295168/how-do-i-fire-a-new-ajax-on-select2-new-remove-tag-event

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do it. There is a example in the documentation. Look at http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#events

```
$("#e11_2").select2({
  createSearchChoice: function(term, data) { 

   if ($(data).filter( function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;   
         }).length===0) {
     return {id:term, text:term};
   } 

  },
  multiple: true,
  data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
});
```

You have to create a function like createSearchChoice, that returns a object with 'id' and 'text'. In other case, if you return undefined the option not will be created.