# select2 to add new tags with confirmation box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

In `Select2` I have basic tagging functionality working. The tagging system is works in an insert project page, where I can tag projects with certain predefined tags that are stored in a database and called by AJAX, and also in an update project page where the same mechanism is at play with the addition of bringing up currently stored tags in the tag field.

I want it so that if no tag currently exists, the user will receive a confirmation box that asks whether or not they want to add a new tag, and by hitting ok that tag will then be stored in the database. There should also be a sort of buffer time of a few seconds for `Select2` to catch up with looking up the tags otherwise it might create duplicates?

I have read something [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ8Fw/) that shows how to do the jquery part, albeit its incomplete for my purposes. Can anyone shed light into how I might do this? I am not looking for complete answers, but merely guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [How do I fire a new ajax on select2 new /remove tag event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295168/how-do-i-fire-a-new-ajax-on-select2-new-remove-tag-event)

In your case, using your fiddle, you can use something like:

```
$('#tags').on("change", function(e){
    if (e.added) {
        if (/ \(new\)$/.test(e.added.text)) {
           // A new tag was added
           // Prompt the user
           var response = confirm("Do you want to add the new tag "+e.added.id+"?");

           if (response == true) {
              // User clicked OK
              console.log("Sending the tag to the server");
              $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/someurl&action=addTag',
                   data: {id: e.added.id, action: add},    
                   error: function () {
                      alert("error");
                   }
               });
           } else {
                // User clicked Cancel
                console.log("Removing the tag");
                var selectedTags = $("#tags").select2("val");
                var index = selectedTags.indexOf(e.added.id);
                selectedTags.splice(index,1);
                if (selectedTags.length == 0) {
                    $("#tags").select2("val","");
                } else {
                    $("#tags").select2("val",selectedTags);
                }
           }
        }
    }
});
```

[Draft fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/y829N/6/).

Comment: Very interesting! and thanks for the linked question. In the PHP script, what variables are sent to `/someurl&action=addTag`? I need to have the term obviously.

Comment: Oh never mind I wasn't paying attention to the data. An error I noticed is if you cancel the confirmation, there is an error where you can still see the box (in your fiddle). Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Hmm. If you are using an old browser, then the code to remove the tags may not work - you will have to use other code to remove an element from an array via JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using the current version of chrome. What are you using?

Comment: Aha - problem was when the new tag is the only tag in the select. Fixed.

Comment: Ah cool! The problem Im having now is that I get the new tag to post via AJAX creating a new tag and id in the tag db, but for obvious reasons the page its on only has the term name, and not the id yet! So instead of a number being stored for the project, the term name is, and now when I go to the update page the newly generated term does not show up because it has to be in a number format! I figured I could fix this on the back-end querying the tags for the project to see if there is a `new` text tag and match it with the id, but is there a more direct approach?

Comment: As part of the AJAX post, you could return the ID of the new tag in the response to the POST request. You add a `success` callback function to the AJAX post call in which you could then associate the new ID with the existing term in the select.

Comment: Thats a bit above my skillset (don't know much about AJAX and jquery), I have configured the PHP to create the term and return the ID for the newly created term but im stuck at that.

Comment: @mccannf with the help of your code i am trying select2. But stuck somewhere, i raised a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216302/jquery-select2-error-in-getting-data-from-php-mysql if possible could you please have a look