# jquery select2: error in getting data from php-mysql

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am testing **select2** plugin in my local machine. 
But for some reason. it is not collecting the data from database.

I tried multiple times but not able to find the issue.

Below are the code .

```
<div class="form-group">

   <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="hidden" id="tags" style="width: 300px"/>
   </div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var lastResults = [];

$("#tags").select2({
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Please enter tags",
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    },
    ajax: {
        multiple: true,
        url: "fetch.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
      data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
            },
        results: function (data) {
            lastResults = data;
            return data;
        }
    },
    createSearchChoice: function (term) {
        var text = term + (lastResults.some(function(r) { return r.text == term }) ? "" : " (new)");
        return { id: term, text: text };
    },
});

$('#tags').on("change", function(e){
    if (e.added) {
        if (/ \(new\)$/.test(e.added.text)) {
           var response = confirm("Do you want to add the new tag "+e.added.id+"?");
           if (response == true) {
              alert("Will now send new tag to server: " + e.added.id);
              /*
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/someurl&action=addTag',
                   data: {id: e.added.id, action: add},    
                   error: function () {
                      alert("error");
                   }
                });
               */
           } else {
                console.log("Removing the tag");
                var selectedTags = $("#tags").select2("val");
                var index = selectedTags.indexOf(e.added.id);
                selectedTags.splice(index,1);
                if (selectedTags.length == 0) {
                    $("#tags").select2("val","");
                } else {
                    $("#tags").select2("val",selectedTags);
                }
           }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

**fetch.php**

i checked fetch.php and it is working fine. It is returning the data.

```
<?php 
    require('db.php');

    $search = strip_tags(trim($_GET['q'])); 
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tid,tag FROM tag WHERE tag LIKE :search LIMIT 4");

    $query->execute(array(':search'=>"%".$search."%"));

    $list = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($list) > 0){
       foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = array('id' => $value['tid'], 'text' => $value['tag']);                
       } 
    } else {
       $data[] = array('id' => '0', 'text' => 'No Products Found');
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

    ?>
```

I am trying to create tagging and it will check tag in database. 
if tag not found then user can create new tag and it will save in database and show in user user selection.

At the moment i am not yet created the page to save the tags in database.
**I tried using select2 version 3.5 and 4.0.1 as well**.

This is first time is i am trying **select2** plugin. So, please ignore if i did silly mistakes. I apologies for that.

Thanks for your time.

**Edit:**

I checked in firebug and found data fetch.php didn't get any value from input box. it looks like issue in Ajax. Because it is not sending q value.

Comment: Try chaning url to use: fetch.php to something like http://localhost/fetch.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer. how to get the data from database.

**tag.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastResults = [];

$("#tags").select2({
    multiple: true,

    //tags: true,    
    placeholder: "Please enter tags",
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    },
    ajax: {
        multiple: true,
        url: "fetch.php",
        dataType: "json",
        delay: 250,
        type: "POST",
      data: function(term,page) {
                        return {q: term};
                        //json: JSON.stringify(),
                    },
                    results: function(data,page) {
                        return {results: data};

                    }, 

    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
      // max tags is 3
    maximumSelectionSize: 3,   
    createSearchChoice: function (term) {
        var text = term + (lastResults.some(function(r) { return r.text == term }) ? "" : " (new)");
       // return { id: term, text: text };
         return {
            id: $.trim(term),
            text: $.trim(term) + ' (new tag)'
        };        
    },
});

$('#tags').on("change", function(e){
    if (e.added) {
        if (/ \(new\)$/.test(e.added.text)) {
           var response = confirm("Do you want to add the new tag "+e.added.id+"?");
           if (response == true) {
              alert("Will now send new tag to server: " + e.added.id);
              /*
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/someurl&action=addTag',
                   data: {id: e.added.id, action: add},    
                   error: function () {
                      alert("error");
                   }
                });
               */
           } else {
                console.log("Removing the tag");
                var selectedTags = $("#tags").select2("val");
                var index = selectedTags.indexOf(e.added.id);
                selectedTags.splice(index,1);
                if (selectedTags.length == 0) {
                    $("#tags").select2("val","");
                } else {
                    $("#tags").select2("val",selectedTags);
                }
           }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php 
// connect to database 
require('db.php');

// strip tags may not be the best method for your project to apply extra layer of security but fits needs for this tutorial 
$search = strip_tags(trim($_POST['term'])); 

// Do Prepared Query 
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tid,tag FROM tag WHERE tag LIKE :search LIMIT 4");

// Add a wildcard search to the search variable
$query->execute(array(':search'=>"%".$search."%"));

// Do a quick fetchall on the results
$list = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Make sure we have a result
if(count($list) > 0){
   foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $value['tag'], 'text' => $value['tag']);            
   } 
} else {
   $data[] = array('id' => '0', 'text' => 'No Products Found');
}


// return the result in json
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

With the above code i am able to get the data from database. I get help from multiple users from SO. Thanks to all of them.

However, i am still refining other areas like adding tag in database. Once it completed i will post full n final code.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration for select2 v4+ differs from v3.5+

It will work for select2 v4:

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="tags-select form-control" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px;">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".tags-select").select2({
  tags: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "fetch.php",
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look. voted up.

Comment: I am trying to implement the same with my code but my inexperience is killing me. Not able to figure out. how to make it working.