# Select2 Event for creating a new tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using the jQuery [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) (v4) plugin for a tag selector.

I want to listen for when a new tag is created in the select element and fire an ajax request to store the new tag. I discovered there is the `createTag` event but this seems to fire every time a letter is entered into the select2 element. As shown in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qkgagwk/1/

Is there a similar event that only fires when the new tag has finished being entered? I.e. it's enclosed by a grey box enclosing it.

Comment: Can't you just use the `:select` event? So every time something is selected, you get it like this: `$(selector).on("select2:select", function (e) { console.log(e.params.data); });`. This indeed does not make a difference between existing vs. new objects, but its a start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295168/how-do-i-fire-a-new-ajax-on-select2-new-remove-tag-event

Comment: `createTag` isn't an event but a method that's overridden. It looks like the developer responded to your question on Gitlab about this the next day (https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3063) - it would have been nice had you updated your question or provided an answer.  For others, the develop suggested listening for the `select2:selected` event; I've found that a `change` event is fired also.

Comment: may the coding gods bless you @Paul

Answer (score 46):

I can't find any *native* method unfortunately. But if you're interested in simple "workarounds", maybe this get you closer:

```
$('.select2').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    createTag: function (tag) {
        return {
            id: tag.term,
            text: tag.term,
            // add indicator:
            isNew : true
        };
    }
}).on("select2:select", function(e) {
    if(e.params.data.isNew){
        // append the new option element prenamently:
        $(this).find('[value="'+e.params.data.id+'"]').replaceWith('<option selected value="'+e.params.data.id+'">'+e.params.data.text+'</option>');
        // store the new tag:
        $.ajax({
            // ... 
        });
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnw96phd/)

---

**[EDIT]**
(Small update: see [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656977/select2-event-for-creating-a-new-tag/28657702#comment78785020_28657702) comment below)

The above will work only if the tag is added with mouse. For tags added by hitting *space* or *comma*, use `change` event.

Then you can filter `option` with `data-select2-tag="true"` attribute (new added tag):

```
$('.select2').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
}).on("change", function(e) {
    var isNew = $(this).find('[data-select2-tag="true"]');
    if(isNew.length && $.inArray(isNew.val(), $(this).val()) !== -1){
        isNew.replaceWith('<option selected value="'+isNew.val()+'">'+isNew.val()+'</option>');
        $.ajax({
            // ... store tag ...
        });
    }
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/qd17suhn/218/)

Comment: How do i detect if the tag was removed ?

Comment: I want only when the new tag is removed event

Comment: Then you could add an indicator (like *class*) when new tag is created and simply check that indicator in `:unselect` event handler. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qd17suhn/6/)

Comment: @did you test your code ? Please try to remove the newly created tag using the bakcspace key! the tag is doubled or something :(

Comment: ? any thoughts about this issue

Comment: Though I haven't tested it much as it was just an example o how you could use it and how does the idea work, so with a little understanding of this conception you can fine-tune it on your own... It just need a small change - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qd17suhn/8/)

Comment: if you type 'aw' and hit enter to select 'awesome' it creates a new tag 'aw' adds it to the selectbox and also adds 'awesome'. obviously the desired behavior is just to add 'awesome' in this case, and not to add a new tag. I think that is what @Sahan was explaining, but I can't figure out a way to prevent this issue.

Comment: @Alex, I can't replicate your issue. If you just type "aw", and hit enter while "aw" is selected, then obviously it creates a new tag "aw". If you want the "awesome" tag to be selected, type "aw", then use arrows key, navigate to the "awesome" tag (highlight it) and then hit enter. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex, ok, sorry, you're right. Now I see what you mean :)

Comment: the authors (of select2) answer seems to answer it using a different method that was hidden in the docs: http://jsfiddle.net/3qkgagwk/2/

Comment: @Alex , It doesn't answer the question actually. Newly created tags remains in the dropdown as long as they're selected. When you unselect the new tag, it disapears from the dropdown aswell. It's the issue. You want the new tag to be sent over AJAX and stored in a database, therefore it should remain as an option to choose even if it's unselected. PS: Fixed the issue in the second example.

Comment: ah for me it works because in my implementation because the element is stored the second the comma or break to next tag is triggered. hence it is gathered via ajax when the user starts typing again should they have deselected it.

Answer (score 2):

The only event listener that worked for me when creating a new tag was:

```
.on("select2:close", function() {
 (my code)
})
```

This was triggered for new tags and selecting from the list. `change`, `select2:select`, `select2:selecting` and any others did not work.

Comment: To distinguish from an existing tag or a new tag I used:
`if(e.params.hasOwnProperty('originalSelect2Event') && e.params.originalSelect2Event.data.isNew == true)`

Answer (score 1):

One more simple check will be this based on the difference in the **args** of the event  .....

While I was dealing with this situation, I had seen this difference; that when the new element is created the event args data does not have an element object but it exists when selecting an already available option...

```
.on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
   if (typeof e.params.args.data.element == 'undefined') {  
      // do a further check if the item created id is not empty..
       if( e.params.args.data.id != "" ){
          // code to be executed after new tag creation
       }
   }
 })
```

[image: See this picture for different condition's event log]

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround. Just insert it to the beginning:

```
           }).on('select2:selecting', function (evt) {

             var stringOriginal = (function (value) {
                // creation of new tag
                if (!_.isString(value)) {
                    return  value.html();
                }
                // picking existing
                return value;
            })(evt.params.args.data.text);
            ........
```

It relies on underscore.js for checking if it's string or not. You can replace _.isString method with whatever you like.

It uses the fact that when new term is created it's always an object.