# Select2 user create tag click event

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using Select 2 v4, and I've included tags: true to let users search for and select new options.  What I'm wanting is to be able to fire specific events when the user chooses their new option instead of an existing option.  So how do I do this?

```
$("#smart_search").select2({
    placeholder: "Start typing what you need...",
    data: data,
    width: '300px',
    formatSelection: function(item) {return item.id},
    formatResult: function(item) {return item.name},
    tags: true
}).on('change', function (e) {
    smart_search = $(this).val();
    console.log('and the value is: ' + smart_search);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I used this workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656977/select2-event-for-creating-a-new-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 Event for creating a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656977/select2-event-for-creating-a-new-tag)