# jquery select2 setting input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I have the following input textbox using select2:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QRY_Owner"> Owner ID</label>
        <input id="QRY_Owner" type="text" style="width:100%">
        </input>
    </div>
</div>
```

which is setupusing select2 like this:

```
            $("#QRY_Owner").select2({
                placeholder: "Owner ID",
                tags: [],
                tokenSeparators: [",", " ", ";"],
                maximumInputLength: 12,
                selectOnBlur: true,
                dropdownCssClass: "hiddenSelect2DropDown"
            });
```

Now, I want to set the default values for the text input. I tried the following:

```
$("#QRY_Owner").select2("val", "test value");
```

and the following:

```
$("#QRY_Owner").select2({
    tags:  ["red", "green", "blue"]
});
```

and the following:

```
 $("#QRY_Owner").val("close");
```

But the form does not get updated and the input fields are blank. Also, I do not get any errors in the browser console.

Any thoughts on what am i missing here?

Here is a jsfiddle which shows my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/snehilw/90m8hzpg/

Comment: First of all, please fix your `<input>`, it does not have a closing tag `</input>` and try to run your code again

Comment: select2 is not for inputs it is for dropdowns <select><option</option></select> of course nothing will be shown in the input.. also you can't pass ("val", "test value"); this isn't php.. you must pass data in JSON format

Comment: As said by @IlanHasanov, you can even read it on the **[Select 2 homepage](https://select2.github.io/)**. You can pass the values your input needs via JQuery on the fly after the element has been created.

Comment: so i tried '$("#QRY_Owner").val("close");' with no luck

Comment: can someone pls give me an example

Comment: @Rookie working on it

Comment: @Rookie, can you clarify what you mean by `tags:  ["red", "green", "blue"]`?

Comment: I was just trying to see if anything gets populated with tags. that seemed to be an option provided by select2 (http://select2.github.io/select2/). you can look at 'Tagging support' section on that page

Comment: @Rookie sadly as stated previously, this only works for select boxes. For now adding a default value to your input is as easy as writing: `$("#QRY_Owner).val("test value");`

Comment: @Rookie <input> doesn't needs to be closed with </input :)

Comment: $("#QRY_Owner).val("test value"); did not work either. No error messages

Comment: workingon a jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle which shows my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/snehilw/90m8hzpg/

Comment: @Rookie part of the problem is that you want to use an `<input>` with `.select2()` where `.select2()` works with `<select>` tags, as specified in the select2 docs. Your JSFiddle is a demonstration of what I just stated. That aside, if you truly want to change the value **after all**, then what you need to do is re-use the `.select2` function (copy/paste) and replace the `placeholder` attribute in it with whatever text you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grabbed from [JQuery select2 set default value from an option in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969666/jquery-select2-set-default-value-from-an-option-in-list).
Just add:

```
.select2('val', ['AL', 'WY'])
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/70/)

Comment: [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90m8hzpg/2/) used `.select2('data',[{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}])`, refer to [Creating new tags in a Select2 tag textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903353/creating-new-tags-in-a-select2-tag-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you want to use an `<input>` with `.select2()` where `.select2()` works with `<select>` tags, as specified in the **[select2 docs](https://select2.github.io/options.html)**.

Your JSFiddle is a demonstration of what I just stated. That aside, if you truly want to change the value after all, then what you need to do is re-use the .select2 function (copy/paste) and replace the placeholder attribute in it with whatever text you want like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var QRY_Owner = $("#QRY_Owner");

  QRY_Owner.select2({
    placeholder: "Owner ID",
    tags: [],
    tokenSeparators: [",", " ", ";"],
    maximumInputLength: 12,
    selectOnBlur: true,
    dropdownCssClass: "hiddenSelect2DropDown"
  });

  QRY_Owner.select2({
    placeholder: "Test text",
    tags: [],
    tokenSeparators: [",", " ", ";"],
    maximumInputLength: 12,
    selectOnBlur: true,
    dropdownCssClass: "hiddenSelect2DropDown"
  });
});
```

Keep in mind, always use `$(document).ready` with JQuery, it's a best practice.